# Save a file generated by android on a computer running an emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluestacks

I am making an app that will be used on an android emulator, type Andy, bluestack4, etc.

This app generates a JSON file, and once generated, I want it saved, but on the computer that runs the emulator, not on the emulator.

Is this possible?

My intention is that when saved, the user is asked in what folder on the computer they want to do, for example:

[image]

I don't care if the solution works on windows or macOS

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can manually move from simulator to pc using Device File Explorer in android studio

Comment: I know, the idea is that the end user can save it directly from the app that runs in the emulator on the pc

Comment: I think you need to write shell script for which get your file(which save in document directory) and move to your desired location in your pc

Comment: Here's link for which helpfull for you https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35563/transfer-data-from-desktop-to-an-emulator